# Does play! framework work with membase, or maybe in general NoSQL database? 

Tags: playframework, membase

Membase seems pretty promising. Just wonder if Play! can work with Membase. Can anyone tried it share some experience and if possible some samples/documentation etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no module (that I know of) for Membase. You may want to check the code for existing NoSQL modules (like [MongoDB](http://www.playframework.org/modules/mongo)) to see how to create your own interface to Membase.

Answer (score 1):

checkout Play's modules (http://www.playframework.org/modules). There are modules for Mongo, Riak, etc. I am currently using Morphia with Play with great success.